# How can I get the real Path from a Macro Path like $(TargetDir)?

Tags: c#, reflection, path, t4

In a t4 text template I'm trying to load a dll using: `Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath)`.

But it returns me the error: **Absolute Path information is required**.

The dll path is: `var dllPath = "$(TargetDir)Project.dll"` or `$(SolutionDir)Project\\bin\\debug\\Project.dll`.

How can I transform **"$(TargetDir)Project.dll"** in his truly form `"C:\Users\....\Project.dll"` before send it to `Assembly.LoadFile`.

Answer (score 1):

In a T4, I use a ttinclude to disable overwriting of results by only allowing it to continue generating code if using a specific named solution configuration called "RegenCodeFiles".

There are a few different ways to resolve paths in this that you may find useful, as well as an assembly resolver that looks through the packages folder (its hard coded and should be looking for the nuget.config).

One thing I would caution against (only because its a troublesome workflow) is trying to refer to an assembly in the TT that the TT is part of.

The include is called like this...

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ include file="CodeGenHelpers.ttinclude" #>
var regenHelper = new CodeGenHelpers(Host);
regenHelper.SetupBinPathAssemblyResolution();

if (regenHelper.ShouldRegenerate() == false)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Not Regenerating File");
    var existingFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(Host.TemplateFile, "cs"); 
    var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(existingFileName);
    return fileContent;
}

Debug.WriteLine($"Regenerating File");
// ...rest of T4
```

**CodeGenHelpers.ttinclude**

```
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0" #>
<#@ assembly Name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
<#+

    public class CodeGenHelpers
    {
        private static string _ConfigName;
        private static bool? _ShouldRegenerate;
        private ITextTemplatingEngineHost _Host;
        private static DTE _Dte;

        public CodeGenHelpers(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host)
        {
            _Host = host;
        }

        public  bool ShouldRegenerate()
        {
            if (_ShouldRegenerate.HasValue == false)
            {
                var configName = GetConfigName();   
                _ShouldRegenerate = "RegenCodeFiles".Equals(configName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }

            return _ShouldRegenerate.Value;
        }

        public string GetConfigName()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_ConfigName))
            {
                _ConfigName = GetDte().Solution.SolutionBuild.ActiveConfiguration.Name;
            }
            return _ConfigName;
        }

        public DTE GetDte()
        {
            if (_Dte == null)
            {
                var serviceProvider = _Host as IServiceProvider;
                _Dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
            }
            return _Dte;
        }

        public void SetupBinPathAssemblyResolution()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveMeh;
        }

        //load from nuget packages first
        public Assembly ResolveMeh(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            var currentFolder = new FileInfo(_Host.ResolvePath(_Host.TemplateFile)).DirectoryName;
            var configName = GetConfigName();
            //probably look at the project properties in DTE, but whatever
            var d = _Dte;
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
            var assemblyLoadFolder = Path.Combine(currentFolder, $"bin\\{configName}");
            var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(assemblyLoadFolder, assemblyName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyPath) == true) 
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
                return assembly;
            }

            //there are nuget services for vs, but they are installed via nuget package, 
            // which is what this is looking for so I dont know if it will work. 
            // https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.VisualStudio


            var solutionFilePath = GetDte().FullName;
            var solutionFile = GetDte().FileName;
            var solutionFolder = solutionFilePath.Replace(solutionFile, string.Empty);
            var packagesFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(solutionFolder, "packages");
            var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(packagesFolder, assemblyName, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(files[0]); //prob also check target fw
                return assembly;
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

#>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  @Erick why haven't you marked this correct yet